# Encontrar dato dentro de un objeto apartir de una ruta como string

Tags: javascript

Lo que deseo es que busque la ruta y devuelva el valor, de no encontrar nada retorne un string vacio, tengo esto de momento y funcion solo que si no encuentra el valor en el objeto da error y para la ejeción:

```js
const data = {
  user:{
    name: "Lupe Moreno",
    email: "lmoreno@gmail.com"
  },
  client:{
    name: "Carlos Faro",
    email: "cfaro@gmail.com"
  }
}

const variables = {
  user_name: 'data.user.name',
  user_email:'data.user.email',
  client_name: 'data.client.name',
  city: 'data.city.name'
}

const template = [
  "user_name",
  "client_name",
  "city"
]

const params = {};
for (const param of template) {
  params[param] = variables[param]
}

const dataFormater = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
  dataFormater[key] = eval(value) || "";
}

console.log(dataFormater)
```

En este caso city no exite en el objeto data por lo cual lo deberia devolver como string vacio.

Answer (score 2):

Algunas aclaraciones. Una forma más segura de acceder a las propiedades de un objeto a través de una cadena de texto es usar el método get() del objeto Reflect. Este método permite acceder a una propiedad de un objeto a través de su nombre, como si fuera una función. Por ejemplo:

```
const propiedad = Reflect.get(objeto, 'propiedad');
```

En tu código podes modificarlo para user `get()` en vez de `eval()`:

```
const dataFormater = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
  dataFormater[key] = Reflect.get(data, value) || "";
}
```

Entonces, si la propiedad que estás tratando de acceder no existe en el objeto, el método get() va a devolver undefined, que luego va a ser convertido a un string vacío al usar el operador OR `(||)`.

Por ultimo, te recomiendo que si bien la forma en que estás usando el ciclo for para iterar sobre el objeto params es correcta, la forma en que estás definiendo los valores de ese objeto (con una cadena de texto que representa una propiedad de otro objeto) no es la forma más clara de hacerlo. Sería más fácil de entender si defines los valores directamente en el objeto params, en lugar de hacerlo a través de otro objeto. Por ejemplo:

```
const params = {
  user_name: data.user.name,
  user_email: data.user.email,
  client_name: data.client.name,
  city: data.city.name
};
```

Saludos

Edit a tu comentario:

claro, porque value es una cadena que contiene el nombre de la propiedad anidada que quieres acceder en el objeto data. En lugar de usar Reflect.get(), podes usar la notación de punto o la notación de corchetes para acceder a la propiedad anidada del objeto data. SI queres probar con tu método, sería asi:

```
eval(`data.${value}`)
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!  revisando  veo que el metodo get no funciona bien cuando se quiere obtener un valor que esta dentro de otro objeto, por ejemplo: Reflect.get(objeto, 'user.name'), asi exista en el objeto retorna undefined

Answer (score 0):

De seguro uno de tus datos te está trayendo `undefined`, prueba con la siguiente validación dentro de tu `for...of`, en donde si te trae `undefined`, retornas vacío al valor:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
  if (data[value] !== undefined) {
    dataFormater[key] = eval(value) || "";
  } else {
    dataFormater[key] = '';
  }
}
```